# VB.NET and MySql UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have my codes here without errors (at least not when I Debug it, I use `VS 2010`), but what I wish to happen is when I click on the add button, the number/s in the textbox(txtQty) would add to the numbers currently saved in the column "Quantity". (ex: txtQty "100" and current on the column is "200", I want to add "100" from the textbox to the column which has "200" and save it as a new number "300". Simple math I know, but the problem is I have yet to know how to use math equations on `VB.NET` `Datagridview` or `MySql Database` This Code executes but when I click Add the numbers in the column return to 0. Any Hint or Tips would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
        cmd.Connection = conn

        Dim Result = "Quantity" + txtQty.Text

        cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE incomingdeliveries SET Quantity ='" & Result & "';"
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Quantity", txtQty.Text))

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Data Added to the Database")

            Me.IncomingdeliveriesTableAdapter.Dispose()
        Me.IncomingdeliveriesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.IncomingDeliveriesDataSet.incomingdeliveries)

            lblCode.Text = ("Tables Refreshed!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your command text must be parameterized also

```
cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE incomingdeliveries SET Quantity = @iQuantity + Quantity"
cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iQuantity", txtQty.Text))
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("connectionStr here")
    Using _comm As New MySqlCommand()
        With _comm
            .Connection = _conn
            .CommandText = "UPDATE incomingdeliveries SET Quantity = @iQuantity + Quantity"
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iQuantity", txtQty.Text)
        End With
        Try
            _conn.Open()
            _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Msgbox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: ok I changed my query to yours thanks for that, now it's able to add, but the problem now is that the whole column is being changed. (ex: I add 100, all columns now get added with 100), also when I click add again i get this error( **Parameter '@iQuantity' has already been defined.**)

Comment: is `cmd` declared globally? *bad*. but you can add `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` before the command text.

Comment: @AlexLuthor one, you should specify the row to be updated using a where clause in your update query (may be with an id?). Two, you should use `var cmd = new ()` rather than use the same SqlCommand field always. In other words instantiate a new instance everytime, preferably with `using` clause. I hope John will amend his answer to reflect that.

Comment: declared globally? hmm if your asking me if I used it in everything yes... I also added the line you gave... and it helped remove the exception. but the other problem remains, would you mind taking a look at it for me if it's ok... I'm really new with VB.NET and MySql and I'm still learning..

Comment: @nawfal `var cmd = new()` so in .net it's `dim cmd = new mysqlcommand` right? hmm and using clause? okay thanks I will read about that... Thanks for your advice..

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me, I hope you could bear with me a little more.. `.Connection = _conn` is this line correct? cause I get an error on this line `  _conn.ExecuteNonQuery()` saying `execute query is not a member of 'mysql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`. shouldn't it be `_comm` instead of `_conn`.. yup I changed it and worked... let me try it now.

Comment: @AlexLuthor you should accept the answer by clicking on the green tick on the top left of the answer, if it helped

Comment: @AlexLuthor sorry for the typo due to *copy and paste*, it was `_comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` not `_conn`

Comment: @John Thanks for everything, last problem is about all the the `Rows` in `Quantity Column` is being added by 100(the input on the textbox)

Comment: @AlexLuthor that's what you want right? if you want for specific record, you should need to add `WHERE` consition on your query something like `WHERE id = @id`

Comment: @John yup this is what  I want... so could I also use `WHERE` on `UPDATE`? cause I always use it on `SELECT`

Comment: @AlexLuthor something like `UPDATE incomingdeliveries SET Quantity = @iQuantity + Quantity WHERE id = @id`, you need to another parameter to `@id`