# unable to update database in mysql with VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am trying to create an update command in VB. I was able to create it and no error is showing.

but when i try to perform the command during debugging, the update doesn't seem to be working. I am not getting any error  during the execution, but no changes are being made on my database.

here is my code..it's a bit long..sorry for that..

```js
connection = New MySqlConnection
        connection.ConnectionString = "Database=ngp;data source=localhost; user id= root; password=********"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

        If MsgBox("Are you sure about the CHANGES you made to " & Label33.Text & " ? " & vbNewLine & "May prob pa sa result ng yesno", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Try
                connection.Open()
                Dim edit As String
                edit = "update ngpmain set ID='" & TextBox21.Text & "',PENRO='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "',CENRO='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "',MUNICIPALITY_or_CITY='" & ComboBox3.SelectedItem & "',BARANGAY='" & TextBox1.Text & "',PROVINCE='" & TextBox2.Text & "',AREA='" & TextBox3.Text & "',SEEDS_PLANTED='" & TextBox4.Text & "',NAME_OF_ORG='" & TextBox5.Text & "',CONTACT_PERSON='" & TextBox6.Text & "',TYPE_OF_ORG='" & ComboBox4.SelectedItem & "',COMPONENT='" & ComboBox5.SelectedItem & "',COMMODITY='" & ComboBox10.SelectedItem & "',SPECIES='" & TextBox8.Text & "',YEAR='" & ComboBox6.SelectedItem & "',ZONE='" & ComboBox7.SelectedItem & "',TENURE='" & TextBox9.Text & "',NO_LOA='" & ComboBox8.SelectedItem & "',RIVER_BASIN='" & TextBox10.Text & "',WATERSHED='" & TextBox11.Text & "',REMARKS='" & TextBox12.Text & "',sid='" & TextBox13.Text & "',sid2='" & TextBox14.Text & "',YR_CD='" & TextBox15.Text & "', PSGC_CD='" & TextBox16.Text & "',SITE_ID='" & TextBox17.Text & "',AREA_CD='" & TextBox18.Text & "', MALE_PLANTER='" & TextBox19.Text & "',FEMALE_PLANTER='" & TextBox20.Text & "',TOTAL_PLANTERS='" & Label31.Text & "',UNIQUE_ID='" & Label33.Text & "',DISTRICT='" & ComboBox9.SelectedItem & "' where UNIQUE_ID='" & Label33.Text & "' "
                command = New MySqlCommand(edit, connection)
                reader = command.ExecuteReader
                
                MsgBox("Changes were successfully applied.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                Me.Show()
                
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                connection.Dispose()
            End Try

        Else
            MsgBox("No changes have been made.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Me.Show()
        End If
```

here is my new code

```js
Using connection As New MySqlConnection("Database=ngp;data source=localhost; user id= root; password=admin")
                Using edit As New MySqlCommand
                    With edit
                        .Connection = connection
                        'ID='" & TextBox21.Text & "', UNIQUE_ID='" & Label33.Text & "',sid='" & TextBox13.Text & "',sid2='" & TextBox14.Text & "',SITE_ID='" & TextBox17.Text & "',AREA_CD='" & TextBox18.Text & "',
                        .CommandText = "update ngpmain set PENRO='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "',CENRO='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "',MUNICIPALITY_or_CITY='" & ComboBox3.SelectedItem & "',BARANGAY='" & TextBox1.Text & "',PROVINCE='" & TextBox2.Text & "',AREA='" & TextBox3.Text & "',SEEDS_PLANTED='" & TextBox4.Text & "',NAME_OF_ORG='" & TextBox5.Text & "',CONTACT_PERSON='" & TextBox6.Text & "',TYPE_OF_ORG='" & ComboBox4.SelectedItem & "',COMPONENT='" & ComboBox5.SelectedItem & "',COMMODITY='" & ComboBox10.SelectedItem & "',SPECIES='" & TextBox8.Text & "',YEAR='" & ComboBox6.SelectedItem & "',ZONE='" & ComboBox7.SelectedItem & "',TENURE='" & TextBox9.Text & "',NO_LOA='" & ComboBox8.SelectedItem & "',RIVER_BASIN='" & TextBox10.Text & "',WATERSHED='" & TextBox11.Text & "',REMARKS='" & TextBox12.Text & "',YR_CD='" & TextBox15.Text & "',PSGC_CD='" & TextBox16.Text & "',MALE_PLANTER='" & TextBox19.Text & "',FEMALE_PLANTER='" & TextBox20.Text & "',TOTAL_PLANTERS='" & Label31.Text & "',DISTRICT='" & ComboBox9.SelectedItem & "'"
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("UNIQUE_ID", Label33.Text)
                    End With
                    Try
                        connection.Open()
                        edit.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        MsgBox("Changes were successfully applied.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                        Me.Show()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message)

                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: You should use parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @donal any idea on how to do that with my code?.thanks

Comment: The problem you are having is that you should be using  ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader. The parameterized queries are for best practice.

Comment: Here is a good example of how to write it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13133096/379855

Comment: i checked the link and altered my codes..but now, it's changing all my data in the table..i only want to update an specific data filtered with the unique ID

Comment: It's a problem with your where clause. Check what is in label33.

Comment: I've added the new code that i altered. It changes all the data in my table.

Answer (score 0):

After slightly rewriting your update statement I noticed you might be missing a column name, which would cause the update to fail:

It occurs right after year

```
edit = 
    "update ngpmain 
    set ID='" & TextBox21.Text & "'
    ,PENRO='" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem & "'
    ,CENRO='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "'
    ,MUNICIPALITY_or_CITY='" & ComboBox3.SelectedItem & "'
    ,BARANGAY='" & TextBox1.Text & "'
    ,PROVINCE='" & TextBox2.Text & "'
    ,AREA='" & TextBox3.Text & "'
    ,SEEDS_PLANTED='" & TextBox4.Text & "'
    ,NAME_OF_ORG='" & TextBox5.Text & "'
    ,CONTACT_PERSON='" & TextBox6.Text & "'
    ,TYPE_OF_ORG='" & ComboBox4.SelectedItem & "'
    ,COMPONENT='" & ComboBox5.SelectedItem & "'
    ,COMMODITY='" & ComboBox10.SelectedItem & "'
    ,SPECIES='" & TextBox8.Text & "'
    ,YEAR='" & ComboBox6.SelectedItem & "'
    ,='" & ComboBox7.SelectedItem & "' <--- missing column name?!!
    ,TENURE='" & TextBox9.Text & "'
    ,NO_LOA='" & ComboBox8.SelectedItem & "'
    ,RIVER_BASIN='" & TextBox10.Text & "'
    ,WATERSHED='" & TextBox11.Text & "'
    ,REMARKS='" & TextBox12.Text & "'
    ,sid='" & TextBox13.Text & "'
    ,sid2='" & TextBox14.Text & "'
    ,YR_CD='" & TextBox15.Text & "'
    , PSGC_CD='" & TextBox16.Text & "'
    ,SITE_ID='" & TextBox17.Text & "'
    ,AREA_CD='" & TextBox18.Text & "'
    , MALE_PLANTER='" & TextBox19.Text & "'
    ,FEMALE_PLANTER='" & TextBox20.Text & "'
    ,TOTAL_PLANTERS='" & Label31.Text & "'
    ,UNIQUE_ID='" & Label33.Text & "'
    ,DISTRICT='" & ComboBox9.SelectedItem & "' 
    where UNIQUE_ID='" & Label33.Text & "' "
```

Comment: sorry, I must have accidentally removed it during posting..but i have it on my program..let me rewrite the code..